# Setting up Better pest VSCode extension with Laravel Sail

Tags: docker, vscode-extensions, laravel-sail, php-pest

Run CMD+SHIFT+P and Better Pest Run.

got
`QueryException    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: nodename nor servname provided`

It success when run `sail pest`

But I don't know how to configure BetterPest VSCode plugin to use docker.